# Why do I get a null pointer exception when I do "myJButton.requestFocus"

Tags: java, focus, jbutton, setfocus

So basically I made a UI with text fields and buttons. I want to have focus on the submit button when the window first starts up, but i get a null pointer exception right on that method.

```
submitBTN.requestFocus();
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Has submitBTN been initialised?

Comment: Have you shadowed the variable, initialise the local variable and not the instance variable?